# Manuscript exceeding page limit

Tags: publications, phd

I have submitted a manuscript to a conference. They accepted double-blind maniscripts. The page limit was 8-10 pages. My manuscript exceeded the page limit by a bit. I had to make a last-minute change and then the manuscript extended a bit into 11th page. I didn't check the page length during the final submission, which was a big mistake. Will the conference consider my manuscript?

Comment: You could email the conference organizers. I have no involvement in this conference so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know.

Comment: depends upon how strict they are. we cannot answer the question.

Comment: How much is 'a bit'? I would strongly suggest figuring out how to get it down to 10 pages and letting the conference organizers know. If only a few lines over, go and look at paragraphs that have only a few words on the last line and edit to shorten by that one line. Usually fairly easy to do...

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you have a very high impact conference that will end up rejecting lots of good submissions, then yes, they might not want to look at papers by careless authors who did not check their final manuscript before submitting. The conference organization software is probably not set up to generate desk rejects, as this option will cause even more complaints.

If you have a conference with a more reasonable acceptance rate in the range of about 20% to 50%, they might not use a silly rule for cutoffs and recognize that last minute changes can throw of the page limit. Reviewers might comment on exceeding the length, but if it is only a couple of lines, they will tend to be reasonable and not apply stricter standards. I for example would be worried about a paper that is longer by a page or more because it feels that the authors want me to tell them what to cut, which is their job and not mine. It also raises an issue of fairness.

If you cannot wait for a decision because there is a deadline for an alternative conference looming, you might write to the PC chair. If this is a top conference, the PC chair might still get annoyed by you as they will have a lot of questions like this. In a conference with only a few hundred submissions, the PC chair will have a bit more bandwidth to deal with nervous authors.

In your interactions with the conference, please be mindful that most of the work is done by volunteers (or graduate students who have been drafted) who do not see any of the conference fees but will (in my experience) be hounded by the organizing institution to fill out forms, give accounts, and sign statements.